# Database connection throws some errors

Tags: c#, database

My program wont launch, I'm getting an error I don't know how to fix. Please advise

I've googled the error

Error 1:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error     Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\KarateStock.exe" to "bin\Debug\KarateStock.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\KarateStock.exe' because it is being used by another process. KarateStock

Error 2:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error       Could not copy "obj\Debug\KarateStock.exe" to "bin\Debug\KarateStock.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: "KarateStock (6744), KarateStock (5932), KarateStock (1196)"  KarateStock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the process hasn't closed since your last debugging session and is still running in memory. Please check your task manager to see if it's still open.

Alternatively, a good way to test this is to close Visual Studio/Restart your PC to see if the problem still occurs.

It looks like you have 3 copies of the program open: KarateStock (6744), KarateStock (5932), KarateStock (1196)" KarateStock

Comment: Thank you! Never would have thought of that.

Comment: You're welcome - can you accept this answer if this has helped you? 
(the green tick on the left)